# Sth Wrong with the CFSocket on ios server side, the callback function is not be called

Tags: ios, sockets, connection, server-configuration, cfsocket

I would like to build an online game on iphone , now I need to code to establish an connection between two players, not bonjour , I must use some socket way to do this.
And here's my code on the client, It works when running on mac, but not work on Iphone device testing. I really has no clue where goes wrong,and this bothers me alot . Anyone has the same problem?
the log says the socket is already listening on the port,but the AcceptCallback function just will not be called,what's wrong?

CFSocketRef sserveripv4;

```
CFSocketContext CTX4 = { 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };

sserveripv4 = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
                         kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, AcceptCallback, &CTX4);

CFSocketRef sserveripv6;

CFSocketContext CTX6 = { 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };

sserveripv6 = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
                             kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, AcceptCallback, &CTX6);

if (sserveripv4 == NULL)
    return -1;
if (sserveripv6 == NULL) {
    return -2;
}

int yes = 1;
setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(sserveripv4), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
           (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(sserveripv6), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
           (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));

struct sockaddr_in sin; 
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));             
sin.sin_len = sizeof(sin);
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;                  
sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);                
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);       
CFDataRef sincfd = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
CFSocketSetAddress(sserveripv4, sincfd);
CFRelease(sincfd);

struct sockaddr_in6 sin6; 
memset(&sin6, 0, sizeof(sin6));             
sin6.sin6_len = sizeof(sin6);
sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;                 
sin6.sin6_port = htons(PORT);                
sin6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;       
CFDataRef sin6cfd = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8*)&sin6, sizeof(sin6));
CFSocketSetAddress(sserveripv6, sin6cfd);
CFRelease(sin6cfd);

CFRunLoopSourceRef socketsource = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, sserveripv4, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), socketsource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

CFRunLoopSourceRef socketsource6 = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, sserveripv6, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), socketsource6, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

printf("Socket listening on port %d\n", PORT);
```

Comment: You got any solution for this ?